# Remove number value from column using Put?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I know we can use the update / remove operator to clear values, but is it possible to use the PUT operator? I don't think sending an empty string value will work since it's a number value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can use `put-item`. With `put-item`, you have to send the entire item, so simply put a version of the item without the attribute.

You may be thinking that DynamoDB enforces a schema but it doesn't. Each item can defines its own set of attributes. Just don't include the attribute in the put if you don't want it.